# Type conversion from string to byte array in Struts 2

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts2, type-conversion

I'm getting some input from the user on client side with no limit on characters. So I am storing input as a BLOB data type.

I am directly getting my entity filled using getters and setters.

**Action class:**

```
public class OperatorNotesAction extends ActionSupport {
    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private OperatorNotesInfo note;
....    
}
```

`OperatorNotesInfo` is the entity I wana get filled. On client side I send the input filled by the user to the action class using JavaScript:

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<s:url action='updateNote'/>",
    data:
    {                   
        'note.title':$('#title').val(),
        'note.id.operatorId':$('#operatorId').val(),
        'note.content':$('textarea').val()

    },
```

Here content is of byte array type in action class as it's stored as a BLOB.

How do I type convert the input entered by the user into byte array, so that content property of the entity `note` gets saved ?

Comment: You want to convert from string to byte array?

Comment: Have you tried to gooogle for how to convert a string to byte array in java?

Comment: Googling or just Stackoverflowing :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom type converter. Strings from input are converted as `String` type by default. You can read [which types conversion is supported via built-in type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25698962/573032).  If you want to convert a string to bytearray you need to write a converter. Then use it with your property

```
@TypeConversion(converter="org.conversion.StringToBytearrayConverter")
public void setContent(byte[] bytes) {
  this.content = bytes;
}
```