# Passing input from jsp to action class

Tags: java, jsp, web, struts2

In my front end, I am allowing user to create and save multiple number of entries to a table at the same time.

For now i am sending this input to Java class in form of string which i am creating at the time of save. But if table size is very very big (eg. 400-500 entries), then creating string is a time taking process.

Is the any other solution for this??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably sending that data over the wire is also `a time taking process`

Comment: I m not very sure but you can try writing in to a file and passing that file , but it definately will be a bad practice if you 're planning less no of entries

Comment: You might consider a forced save (e.g. every 50 rows).  Prevents things like 'OMG web server is down an I lost 2 hours of work'.

Answer (score 0):

Send them as a `List`.

In Action:

```
private List<String> myList;

/* GETTER AND SETTER */
```

In JSP, handle a **counter**, and each time the user create a new row, use it to index the row:

```
<input type="text" name="myList[0]" />
<input type="text" name="myList[1]" />
<input type="text" name="myList[2]" />
```

and next time the user will create an entry, it will be

```
<input type="text" name="myList[3]" />
```

If the user creates the entries from, let's say, a popup or a modal dialog, and they won't be editable after having been created, then generate an `<input type="hidden" />` field along with a `<span>` (or whatever):

```
<input type="hidden" name="myList[3]" value="lastValueEnteredByUser" />
<span>lastValueEnteredByUser</span>
```

Comment: Read both the question and the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15267703/1654265