# Map Struts2 form to a Bean with Collection field

Tags: jsp, collections, struts2

I have the Person & Fruit bean defined like this:

```
public class Person {
    private String fullName;
    private List<Fruit> favoriteFruits;
    //getters setters and constructors here.
    ...
}

public class Fruit {
    private String name;
    //getter setter and constructors here.
}
```

Then I have a Struts2 Action like this:

```
public class AddPersonAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1856680463263215989L;

    private Person person;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {      
        if (person!= null) {            
            //TODO add person to database.          
            return SUCCESS;
        } else {            
            return INPUT;
        }
    }    
}
```

And the Strus2 html form looks like this:

```xml
...
<form...>
  <s:textfield name="person.fullName"/>

  <!--This is where I would allow user to create one or more textboxes using javascript. 
    And allow them to input multiple favorite fruits -->

  <s:submit name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
...
```

Now, my question, the way I have mapped textfield named `person.fullName` directly to the Person bean's `fullName` property, how can I map the multiple textboxes (favorite fruit) to the Person bean's `favoriteFruits` collection (`List<Fruit>`) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send back a Collection instead of a single value, [use an index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15343980/1654265).

```xml
<s:textfield value="person.favoriteFruits[0].name" />
<s:textfield value="person.favoriteFruits[1].name" />
...
```

To create it with Javascript, follow [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15267703/1654265) and simply do the math.

Also remember to [always specify a no-args constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19562738/1654265) (if creating a constructor yourself, otherwise it's not necessary since it's there by default) to allow Struts2 map correctly