# Struts 2 - Unexpected Exception caught setting 'xx'

Tags: java, jsp, configuration, struts2, interceptor

I am trying to submit unknown number input from HTML Form to Action class and fetch the Input parameter information by using request Method(Used ServletActionContext) in the Action class.

But its throwing

`Unexpected Exception caught setting 'xx' on 'class classname Error setting expression 'xx' with value ['yy', ]`

Since input elements in the form are adding dynamically using JS, i am not in the position to have getters and setters in the Action class.

How to process the Action class without any exceptions?

**JSP:**

```jsp
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Team Activity Log</title>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(tableid)
{
 var table = document.getElementById(tableid);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("select");
    element1=document.getElementById("sele").cloneNode(true);
    element1.type="select";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type="text";
    element2.setAttribute("placeholder","E.g:1234");
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type="text";
    element3.setAttribute("placeholder","Brief your work");
    cell3.appendChild(element3);

    var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    element4.type="text";
        element4.setAttribute("placeholder","MM min");
    cell4.appendChild(element4);


    var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
    var element5 = document.createElement("img");
    element5.src="close.png";
        element5.setAttribute("id","delete");
        element5.setAttribute("onclick","changeImage(this)");
    cell5.appendChild(element5);



    }
function changeImage(temp)
{
(temp.parentElement).parentElement.remove();
}
function convert(tableid,temp2)
{
var table=document.getElementById(tableid);
console.log(table.rows.length);
var hidelement=document.getElementById(temp2);
hidelement.setAttribute("value",table.rows.length-1);
for(var i=1;i<table.rows.length;i++)
{
var tt="tt"+i;
var rf="rf"+i;
var des="des"+i;
var eff="eff"+i;
console.log("executing function");
var elemen=table.rows[i].cells[0].querySelector("*");
elemen.setAttribute("name",tt);
elemen=table.rows[i].cells[1].querySelector("*");
elemen.setAttribute("name",rf);
elemen=table.rows[i].cells[2].querySelector("*");
elemen.setAttribute("name",des);
elemen=table.rows[i].cells[3].querySelector("*");
elemen.setAttribute("name",eff);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('matrix')" />
    <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
    <s:url id="myActionUrl" action="timesheetprocess" />
    <form action=<s:property value="%{myActionUrl}" />> 
    <input type="hidden" id="taskcount" value="5">
<table id="matrix">
<tr>
    <th>Task Type</th>
    <th>Reference ID</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Efforts</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
  <select id="sele">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
           <option value="SR">SR</option>
           <option value="CR">CR</option>
           <option value="ALM">ALM</option>
           <option value="INCIDENT">INCIDENT</option> 
           <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
   </select></TD>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="E.g:1234"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="Brief your work"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="MM min" />
   </td>
   <td>
   <img id="delete" src="close.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
   </td>
   </tr><tr>
  <td>
  <select id="sele">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
           <option value="SR">SR</option>
           <option value="CR">CR</option>
           <option value="ALM">ALM</option>
           <option value="INCIDENT">INCIDENT</option> 
           <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
   </select></TD>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="E.g:1234"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="Brief your work"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="MM min" />
   </td>
   <td>
   <img id="delete" src="close.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>
  <select id="sele">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
           <option value="SR">SR</option>
           <option value="CR">CR</option>
           <option value="ALM">ALM</option>
           <option value="INCIDENT">INCIDENT</option> 
           <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
   </select></TD>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="E.g:1234"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="Brief your work"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="MM min" />
   </td>
   <td>
   <img id="delete" src="close.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>
  <select id="sele">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
           <option value="SR">SR</option>
           <option value="CR">CR</option>
           <option value="ALM">ALM</option>
           <option value="INCIDENT">INCIDENT</option> 
           <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
   </select></TD>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="E.g:1234"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="Brief your work"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="MM min" />
   </td>
   <td>
   <img id="delete" src="close.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
   </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>
  <select id="sele">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
           <option value="SR">SR</option>
           <option value="CR">CR</option>
           <option value="ALM">ALM</option>
           <option value="INCIDENT">INCIDENT</option> 
           <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
   </select></TD>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="E.g:1234"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="Brief your work"/>
   </td>
   <td>
   <INPUT type="text" placeholder="MM min" />
   </td>
   <td>
   <img id="delete" src="close.png" onclick="changeImage(this)">
   </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
    <INPUT type="button" value="Submit" onclick="convert('matrix','taskcount')" />
 </form> 
   </body>
   </html>
```

Action tag in struts.xml

```xml
<action name="timesheetprocess" class="com.App.Controller.Timesheet.Timeprocess"
    method="execute">
    <result name="success">Time.jsp</result>
</action>
```

My Action class:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;

public class Timeprocess {
    public String execute() {

        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        String tt="tt";
        String rf="rf";
        String des="des";
        String eff="eff";

        for(int i=0;i<Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("taskcount"));i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Task Type :"+ request.getParameter(tt+String.valueOf(i)));
            System.out.println("Task Type :"+ request.getParameter(rf+String.valueOf(i)));
            System.out.println("Task Type :"+ request.getParameter(des+String.valueOf(i)));
            System.out.println("Task Type :"+ request.getParameter(eff+String.valueOf(i)));


        }
        return "success";

}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15267703/1654265

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the process of parameters population by Struts2 via overriding interceptors in the action config.

```xml
<action name="timesheetprocess" class="com.App.Controller.Timesheet.Timeprocess"
            method="execute">
   <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack">
      <param name="params.excludeParams">.*</param>
   </interceptor-ref>
   <result name="success">Time.jsp</result>
</action>
```

There you modify the `excludeParams` property of the `params` interceptor to exclude all parameters from processing via OGNL.

You should not get any exception in this way, but make sure you have configured `struts.devMode=false`

```xml
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
```

It should remove unnecessary warnings from the output. If you still get any warnings or exceptions in the log, then you should configure your logging framework to suppress those warnings or errors from the output.